# EDOMParseError with HTML inner XML

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-parsing, delphi-xe2

I have an XML string stored in a variable:

```
<RESULT>
    <ROW>
        <MESSAGE>
            <!DOCTYPE HTML>
            <html>
                <body>
                    hello html inner xml on delphi
                </body>
            </html>
        </MESSAGE>
    </ROW>
</RESULT>
```

I use the following code to parse the string into a `TXmlDocument` object:

```
var
    xmldoc : TXmlDocument;
begin
    xml := LoadXmlData(resultXml);
end;
```

However, it produces the error:

```
EDOMParseError line 1 : <RESULT><ROW><MESSAGE><doctype html>
```

How can I parse this Xml such that I can retrieve the contents of the MESSAGE node?

Comment: Your xml isn't valid XML. You need to wrap the contents of MESSAGE up in <![CDATA[***<RESULT><ROW><MESSAGE><!doctype html>***]]> for example or similarly escape the contents of the message.

Comment: @dash i again taking like this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working on the assumption that the asterisks are just there for highlighting purposes, you have the two options.

If you want to parse the nested HTML as XML, you will need to remove the HTML DOCTYPE declaration.

If there's no need to parse the nested HTML, you could wrap it in a [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#CDATA_sections_in_XML) section as follows:

```
<RESULT>
   <ROW>
       <MESSAGE><![CDATA[
           <!DOCTYPE HTML>
           <html><body>hello html inner xml on delphi</body></html>
       ]]></MESSAGE>
   </ROW>
</RESULT>
```

Comment: i taking this error like this EDOMParseError line 1 <RESULT><ROW>![CDATA[<!doctype